# A Simple Example – Backbone.js Tutorial – Collection based on JSON + View

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I try [this](http://blog.joelberghoff.com/2012/07/22/backbone-js-tutorial-part-1/) tutorial .

The `HTML` is  (**index.html**) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="json2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="backbone.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(function () {
            var Profile = Backbone.Model.extend();

            var ProfileList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: Profile,
                url: 'jsonSample.json'
            });

            var ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: "#profiles",
                template: _.template($('#profileTemplate').html()),
                render: function (eventName) {
                    _.each(this.model.models, function (profile) {
                        var profileTemplate = this.template(profile.toJSON());
                        $(this.el).append(profileTemplate);
                    }, this);

                    return this;
                }
            });

            var profiles = new ProfileList();
            var profilesView = new ProfileView({ model: profiles });
            profiles.fetch();
            profiles.bind('reset', function () {
                profilesView.render();
            });

        });
    </script>
    <title>Fortified Studio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="profiles"></div>

    <script id="profileTemplate" type="text/template">
        <div class="profile">
            <div class="info">
                <div class="name">
                    <%= name %>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                    <%= title %>
                </div>
                <div class="background">
                    <%= background %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**jsonSample.json:**

```
{
    {
        "name" : "AAAA",
        "title" : "BBBB",
        "background" : "CCCC"
    },
    {
        "name" : "DDDD",
        "title" : "EEEE",
        "background" : "FFFF"
    },
    {
        "name" : "GGGG",
        "title" : "HHHH",
        "background" : "IIII"
    }
}
```

But nothing shown on the browser    . What is wrong here ?

Comment: I have not really much experience in Backbone, but your JSON file contains a hash with other hashes inside, shouldn't it be an array containing hashes ?

Comment: @htatche : you right , now the json file is in correct format but still I have same problem .

Comment: Also, once you fix this, you need to print a collection, so you have to iterate over it with somethin like `<% _.each(items,function(item,key,arr) { <%= item %> }); %>`

Comment: I think that's what `template: _.template($('#profileTemplate').html())` used for .

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT 2:**

Here is a jsFiddle for a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/8RP89/1/

I would suggest you look for a different tutorial. This one seems really off and I had to make a quite a few changes to get things working. I wouldn't use my example as a template for future code though. I just did enough to make sure it worked.

The one thing I didn't test out was actually loading the JSON file. Not sure how to do that in jsFiddle.

Here is a a quick overview of the changes I made:

First off, I think that the `reset` event is no longer called on `fetch` unless you specifically ask for reset to be called on fetch:

```
profiles.bind('reset', function () {
    profilesView.render();
});
```

Instead it would be better to listen to an `add` event in your view during initialization. Example:

```
initialize: function(){
    this.listenTo(this.collection,"add", this.renderItem);          
},
```

Now since the `add` event is called for each item added, you need to add method to render items individually

```
renderItem: function(profile) {
     var profileTemplate = this.template(profile.toJSON());
     this.$el.append(profileTemplate);        
}
```

The above doesn't work if you have elements already in the collection, so you'll need to add a render method to handle existing collection elements:

```
render: function () {
    this.collection.each(function(model){
         var profileTemplate = this.template(model.toJSON());
         this.$el.append(profileTemplate);
    }, this);        
    return this;
},
```

Now you must call render explicitly after you create your view:

```
var profilesView = new ProfileView({ collection: profileList });
profilesView.render();
```

**EDIT 1:**

You'll probably want to change these two lines to use collection instead of model. By default collection objects can be accessed in Backbone Views using `this.collection`. The syntax in the tutorial looks completely wrong. I've never seen `this.model.models` before. Maybe this was an older version of Backbone.

```
var profilesView = new ProfileView({ collection: profiles });
```

and this line here:

```
_.each(this.collection, function (profile) {
```

The code you have shows:

```
_.each(this.model.models, function (profile) {
```

and:

```
var profilesView = new ProfileView({ model: profiles });
```

And I'd probably change your json file to use an array:

```
[
    {
        "id": "p1",
        "name" : "AAAA",
        "title" : "BBBB",
        "background" : "CCCC"
    {
        "id": "p2",
        "name" : "DDDD",
        "title" : "EEEE",
        "background" : "FFFF"
    },
    {
        "id": "p3",
        "name" : "GGGG",
        "title" : "HHHH",
        "background" : "IIII"
    }
]
```

Comment: Your changes seems correct but still I get nothing in the browser , does it work for you ?

Comment: Yeah I'm working on a jsFiddle for you. There are a few more errors that I spotted.

Comment: Can you share it here please ?

Comment: Yes, I will post it here. Just working through some syntax errors.

Comment: I updated my answer. Not sure if you get notifications for that. Hope it helps. Unfortunately I was not able to test if the JSON fetch worked in jsFiddle, but you should be able to modify it to use JSON from another url fairly easily.

Comment: So you say it could same just the same code but without `startData` and `addData` and load it from `.json`  file instead  ?

Comment: Yeah I believe so. Just try calling `profileList.fetch()` and remove the parts where I load the `startData` and `addData`